# change legend color using highchart-ng

Tags: highcharts-ng

I want to change legend color in highchart. I have used highchart-ng, the below code its not working, Please help me

```
            scope.dvBarChartNG = {      
                options: {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column',
                        backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
                    }
                },           
                xAxis: {

                },
                yAxis: {

                },                
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                },
                *legend: {
                    itemStyle: {                            
                        'color' : '#000'
                    },
                    itemHoverStyle: {
                        'color' : '#000'
                    },
                    itemHiddenStyle: {  
                        'color' : '#000'
                    }
                },*
                series: [{
                    name: 'xxxx',
                    data: scope.yyyy.series.user,           
                    color: '#cfffac',
                    borderColor: "#cfffac",
                    showInLegend: true
                }, {
                    name: 'xxxx',
                    data: scope.yyyy.series.entity,
                    color: '#82c84c',
                    borderColor: "#82c84c",
                    showInLegend: true
                }]
            };
```

my html code is

Comment: the above asking my question is not properly rendered. my html code is <highchart id="aaa" class="barchart-container" config="dvBarChartNG"></highchart>

Comment: Finally i got a sollution                                                                                                                           options: {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'column',
                            backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
                        },
      legend: {
       itemStyle: {       
        'color' : '#000'
       },
       itemHoverStyle: {
        'color' : '#000'
       },
       itemHiddenStyle: { 
        'color' : '#000'
       }
      }
                    }

Comment: Awesome I was also stuck here , your solution helped me :)